# checking number is power of 2 for numbers greater than 2^64, implementation of manual division

Tags: java, string, character, division

I am trying to check if a number (input as a `String`) is a power of 2. The problem is that the number might be greater than `2^64` (long long limit). If I store it in `double` then I cannot do binary operations on it (so the trick `v & (v - 1) == 0` does not work). Here is the solution I stumbled upon:

```
public class Solution {
    public int power(String A) {

        String dividend = A;
        StringBuilder str;

        if (A == null || A.length() == 0)
            return 0;

        if (A.length() == 1 && A.charAt(0) == '0')
            return 0;

        while (dividend.length() > 0 && !dividend.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            str = new StringBuilder();
            int carry = 0;
            int n = dividend.length();

            if (n > 0) {
                int num = dividend.charAt(n - 1) - '0';

                if (num % 2 == 1)
                    return 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                char c = (char) (dividend.charAt(i) - '0');
                int res = c + 10 * carry;

                c = (char) (res / 2 + '0');
                carry = res % 2;

                str.append(c);
            }

            if (str.charAt(0) == '0')
                str.deleteCharAt(0);

            dividend = str.toString();
        }

        return 1;

    }

}
```

I am having problems understanding the solution. The first check is done if a number is odd or not. I am having problems understanding the implementation of the manual division  done in this problem (especially the arithmetic operations involving both char and int). I get that `'0' == 48` and subtracting `'0'` from a character converts it into integer value. Can anyone explain to me how this division operation has been implemented here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand this implementation is a pen and paper test. I will skip the part you understood and focus only on the last `for` loop.

Let's take `"50"` as an example-input. The loop steps through the `String` character-wise, starting on the left. Therefore, the first character processed is the `'5'`. As you know, `5` is odd. This means we have to "carry" something into the next division. The result of `5 / 2` is `2`. This `2` will be the first digit of the result in the division. Notice that if we reverse our steps, we get `2 * 2`, which is `4`. This is the reason we have to carry something over (the `1` missing, since `5 - 4` is `1`). You may notice that, if you divide by 2, you can either carry `0` (nothing) or `1` (if and only if the dividend is odd).

Now on to the next digit, which is `0`. We have to carry the `1` from the last division over to this step. Since we moved one digit to the left, a `1` from the previos step becomes a `10` in this step. We moved "one order of magnitude down", therefore we have to multiply the carryed part by `10`. This means we calculate `(0 + (1 * 10)) / 2`, which is `10 / 2` = `5`. This `5` is the second digit of the result. Since the dividend is even, we need nothing to carry over.

The final ouput therefore is `"25"`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    str = new StringBuilder();
    int carry = 0;
    int n = dividend.length();

    if (n > 0) {
        int num = dividend.charAt(n - 1) - '0';
```

divided is input. It takes character at the end of string, and from that value takes value of '0'
http://www.asciitable.com/ - for '0' it is 48. So it gives value of that decimal w/o any parsing.

```
        if (num % 2 == 1)
            return 0;
    }
```

Next for loop divides `divided` by two. It is done by dididing each digit. Starting from first one till last. Next iteration gets carry value from prev.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        char c = (char) (dividend.charAt(i) - '0');
```

As before goes here - it 'c' is byte with decimal value.

```
        int res = c + 10 * carry;
```

'res' has also carry.

```
        c = (char) (res / 2 + '0');
```

Division of particular entry is done here. Adding '0' is simple conversion to character / string,

```
        carry = res % 2;
```

Note that we are going from start, not from the end. So carry that goes
to next iteration is modulo.

```
        str.append(c);
    }

    if (str.charAt(0) == '0')
        str.deleteCharAt(0);
```

Just remove leading zeros

```
    dividend = str.toString();
```

Convert back to string, and call divide once again.

Answer (score 0):

//try this!

```
    double n = scanner.nextInt();

    while (n > 1) {
        n = n / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n == 1)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```